# Change the size of one plot only in ggarrange()

Tags: r

I am attempting to make a 2x2 plot using ggarrange(). I would like to make the fourth plot half the height of the other three plots.

I have attempted a solution with the heights argument but it seems to work only on columnwise operations.

```
fig1 <- ggarrange(p1,p2,p3,p4,
                  labels = 'auto',
                  ncol = 2,
                  nrow = 2,
                  common.legend = TRUE,
                  legend = 'top', 
                  heights = c(2, 2, 2, 1),
                  widths=c(1, 1, 1, 1))
```

Comment: You probably should load the packages you are using

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `heights` and `widths` arguments to `ggpubr::ggarrange()` only take the relative sizes for each row or column, not individual plots. From the documentation:

> widths
>
> (optional) numerical vector of relative columns widths. For example, in a two-column grid, widths = c(2, 1) would make the first column twice as wide as the second column.

There are some ways you might work around this:

```r
# Load packages
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
```

**Method 1: Combine a plot with a blank plot to make it half size and use `ggarrange()` twice.**

```r
p1 <- ggplot(iris, aes(x = Sepal.Width, y = Sepal.Length, color = Species)) +
    geom_point()

blank <- ggplot() + geom_blank() + theme_void()
p1_half_size <- ggarrange(
    p1, blank,
    nrow = 2,
    ncol = 1,
    common.legend = TRUE,
    legend = "top"
)
```

```r
ggarrange(
    p1, p1, p1, p1_half_size,
    labels = "auto",
    nrow = 2,
    ncol = 2,
    common.legend = TRUE,
    legend = "top"
)
```

[image]

Works alright, but it fails to combine that nested legend as specified with `common.legend = TRUE`. If you don't need a common legend, then it works well.

**Method 2: Use `ggplot2::theme()` to add a margin to a plot.**

```r
p1_bottom_margin <- p1 +
    theme(plot.margin = margin(5.5, 5.5, 100, 5.5))

ggarrange(
    p1, p1, p1, p1_bottom_margin,
    labels = "auto",
    nrow = 2,
    ncol = 2,
    common.legend = TRUE,
    legend = "top"
)
```

[image]

This works nicely, but depending on the plotting area you specify for export, you may have to fine tune the margin with trial-and-error.